# Eliminate duplicates between columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I have below table (small part of larger table):

```
| B11_1_siknr | B11_2_siknr | B12_siknr | B21_siknr | B22_1_siknr | B22_2_siknr | B31_siknr | B32_siknr | B41_siknr | B42_siknr |
|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 6029879318  | 6020430002  | NULL      | NULL      | 6029879318  | 6020430002  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
```

I have 10 columns with an ID number - however I want to eliminate any duplicates in an efficient manner. I kind of want to avoid having to do a `CASE WHEN` that becomes increasingly more complex the more columns I add.

Maybe this is the only solution - but I wanted to see if anyone had any better ideas on how to achieve this. I don't really mind which ones get eliminated or not - as long as I am left with only unique values across the columns (I guess it may be easiest to start by keeping the most left value and moving to the right - but I am open to suggestions).

My expected result is something like this:

```
| B11_1_siknr | B11_2_siknr | B12_siknr | B21_siknr | B22_1_siknr | B22_2_siknr | B31_siknr | B32_siknr | B41_siknr | B42_siknr |
|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 6029879318  | 6020430002  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL        | NULL        | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way by pivoting and unpivoting

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN val IS NOT NULL
                       AND Row_number()OVER(partition BY val ORDER BY ord) = 1 THEN val
                  ELSE NULL
                END val,
                ord
         FROM   Yourtable
                CROSS apply (VALUES ([B11_1_siknr],1),([B11_2_siknr],2),([B12_siknr],3),([B21_siknr],4),
                                    ([B22_1_siknr],5),([B22_2_siknr],6),([B31_siknr],7),([B32_siknr],8),
                                    ([B41_siknr],9),([B42_siknr],10))tc (val, ord))
SELECT B11_1_siknr = [1],
       B11_2_siknr = [2],
       ...
FROM   cte
       PIVOT (Max(val)
             FOR ord IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]))pv
```

- [**Rextester Demo**](http://rextester.com/JLNN59024)

Comment: This seems to only work with one row of data, however I have 1.700 rows similar to above :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpivot:

```
if object_id('dbo.pvt') is not null drop TABLE dbo.pvt 
CREATE TABLE dbo.pvt 
(   
    id int identity(1,1),
    B11_1_siknr int, B11_2_siknr int, B12_siknr int, B21_siknr int, B22_1_siknr int, B22_2_siknr int, B31_siknr int, B32_siknr int, B41_siknr int, B42_siknr int
);  

INSERT INTO dbo.pvt (B11_1_siknr, B11_2_siknr , B12_siknr , B21_siknr , B22_1_siknr , B22_2_siknr , B31_siknr , B32_siknr , B41_siknr , B42_siknr) VALUES (1,4,3,5,4,4,1,4,3,5);  
INSERT INTO dbo.pvt (B11_1_siknr, B11_2_siknr , B12_siknr , B21_siknr , B22_1_siknr , B22_2_siknr , B31_siknr , B32_siknr , B41_siknr , B42_siknr) VALUES (2,4,1,5,5,5,2,4,1,5);  
INSERT INTO dbo.pvt (B11_1_siknr, B11_2_siknr , B12_siknr , B21_siknr , B22_1_siknr , B22_2_siknr , B31_siknr , B32_siknr , B41_siknr , B42_siknr) VALUES (3,4,3,5,4,4,3,4,3,5);  
INSERT INTO dbo.pvt (B11_1_siknr, B11_2_siknr , B12_siknr , B21_siknr , B22_1_siknr , B22_2_siknr , B31_siknr , B32_siknr , B41_siknr , B42_siknr) VALUES (4,4,2,5,5,4,4,4,2,5);  
INSERT INTO dbo.pvt (B11_1_siknr, B11_2_siknr , B12_siknr , B21_siknr , B22_1_siknr , B22_2_siknr , B31_siknr , B32_siknr , B41_siknr , B42_siknr) VALUES (5,5,1,5,5,5,5,5,1,5);  

--unpivot
SELECT id, ptb, sikn
FROM   
   (SELECT id, B11_1_siknr, B11_2_siknr , B12_siknr , B21_siknr , B22_1_siknr , B22_2_siknr , B31_siknr , B32_siknr , B41_siknr , B42_siknr
   FROM  dbo.pvt ) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (sikn FOR ptb IN   
      (B11_1_siknr, B11_2_siknr , B12_siknr , B21_siknr , B22_1_siknr , B22_2_siknr , B31_siknr , B32_siknr , B41_siknr , B42_siknr)  
)AS unpvt; 

--unpivot distinct 
SELECT distinct sikn
FROM   
   (SELECT id, B11_1_siknr, B11_2_siknr , B12_siknr , B21_siknr , B22_1_siknr , B22_2_siknr , B31_siknr , B32_siknr , B41_siknr , B42_siknr
   FROM  dbo.pvt ) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (sikn FOR ptb IN   
      (B11_1_siknr, B11_2_siknr , B12_siknr , B21_siknr , B22_1_siknr , B22_2_siknr , B31_siknr , B32_siknr , B41_siknr , B42_siknr)  
)AS unpvt; 


--dynamic unpivot
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) = (SELECT ((SELECT N',' + name from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('dbo.pvt') and name like '%siknr' for xml path(''), type).value('substring(./text()[1],2)','nvarchar(max)')));
--print @cols;

-- Unpivot the table.  
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 
N'SELECT id, ptb, sikn
FROM   
   (SELECT id, ' + @cols + N'
   FROM  dbo.pvt ) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (sikn FOR ptb IN   
      (' + @cols + N')  
)AS unpvt'; 
EXEC(@sql);

-- Unpivot distinct the table.  
set @sql = 
N'--distinct ids
SELECT sikn
FROM   
   (SELECT id, ' + @cols + N'
   FROM  dbo.pvt ) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (sikn FOR ptb IN   
      (' + @cols + N')  
)AS unpvt; '; 
EXEC(@sql);
```